# Manual calculation Studentized (rstandard)

Tags: regression

How to calculate manually Studentized measure similar to "rstandard" with following actual and predicted values.

```
actual = c(16,9,17,14,13,23,26,14,27,25)
pred = c(15.0,6.1,17.2,11.3,8.8,22.6,24.6,10.7,25.6,25.2)
```

Comment: There are multiple meanings to a "studentized" residual.  For most of them, it is not enough to have just the residuals: you need additional information about the standard error of each residual (information that usually is computed from the model and how it was fit).  Thus, for this question to be specifically answerable, please tell us what you mean by "Studentized" and how exactly these residuals were obtained.

Comment: Actual and Predicted values are updated. One of my goal is to get QQ plot with these data and need Studentized transformation similar to "rstandard" function in R